# SQL Server Workflow Peristence is configure d with a non-existent store: bogus message, cannot solve

Tags: sql-server, persistence, appfabric

So I've had a Windows Workflow with persistence enabled and all has been well for a month now.  This morning, things came crashing down with the error below.  The problem is, a persistence store HAS been configured and working perfectly (in SQL Server).  Absolutely nothing has changed.  The database where the persistence information is stored is still there and healthy.  We can find no problems with the database itself.  No matter what we do, the list of available servers that should show up in the "Sql Server Store" dropdown remains empty.

It gets worse.  The error isn't restricted to one server.  It has happened organization-wide on several machines (we're using AppFabric with persistence enabled on multiple servers here).  We've tried creating new databases on different servers running separate instances of SQL Server--same result.  Our theory, such as it is, is that Microsoft pushed out some strange update via automatic updates overnight.

Clues, anyone?  TIA
 [image]

Comment: Permissions/firewalls? Can the user running the configuration access the server running the DB as well as login to the DB?

Comment: Also, check the web.configs on all levels (up to root). The persistence stores should be defined in <instanceStores> somewhere, IIRC.